# Apple apps can't connect to the internet after upgrading to macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, network

My father just updated his laptop to macOS Ventura, and now apps from Apple are unable to do anything that requires a network connection. It's not a general internet issue since Chrome and Firefox work as expected, so I assume it's related to how Apple's own apps handle the connection. Neither Safari, nor the App Store, nor the Software Updates section in settings are able to lmake a connection to the internet.

Comment: It works fine here (and I'd suggest for most people), so it's not a problem with the software in itself. Do Chrome and Firefox use their own proxy or network connections? Have you checked that the Network settings are as they should be? Can you use `ping` in the Terminal? (Try something like `ping 8.8.8.8`, which is a Google DNS server.) Also: what exactly happens -- do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be Norton 360, which I did not know was installed on his mac.